# How to correctly handle a response from the Bing Search API in Java?

Tags: java, json, search, bing, bing-api

I am successfully downloading images from the `Bing's-Search-API` in `Java`. However, I don't understand how to handle responses.

For instance, if images are not found, or if the user tries to search for adult content (even if it is set to moderate), how should I `catch` theses responses?

Thank you very much.

Here is my code:

```
public void SearchWithBing(String search){

        search = search.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        String accountKey="acKey";
        byte[] accountKeyBytes = Base64.encodeBase64((accountKey + ":" + accountKey).getBytes());
        String accountKeyEnc = new String(accountKeyBytes);
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(
                    "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Image?Query=%27" + search + "%27&$top=50&$format=json");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + accountKeyEnc);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));
        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");

        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                gsonParser(output);
                System.out.println(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       //EndOfBingSearch  
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Gson:

```
    Gson gson = (new GsonBuilder()).create();
BingSearchResults bingSearchResults = gson.fromJson(res, BingSearchResults.class);
```

with the following class:

```
public class BingSearchResults {

public ResultsContent d;

public static class ResultsContent {
    public Result[] results;
    public String __next;
}

public static class Result {
    public String ID;
    public String Title;
    public String Description;
    public String DisplayUrl;
    public String Url;
    public Metadata __metadata;

}

public static class Metadata {
    public String uri;
    public String type;
}

}
```

Comment: Yeah. This is old. I ended up doing that same thing, but forgot to update the post.